# Mocking an ES6 class from a library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app

I have a `WindowEnv` ES6 class in a library, which I am trying to mock. The class is in a package called `@react-force/models` which my React app depends on. Here's the code for the `WindowEnv` class:

```
// Env.ts in @react-force/models
export interface Env {
    get: (varName: string) => string;
}

export class WindowEnv implements Env {
    get(varName: string): string {
        return (window as any)._env_[varName];
    }
}
```

Here's the code that is using this class in my application:

```
const env = new WindowEnv();
export const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: env.get('API_URL'),
});
```

I have tried to mock the `WindowEnv` class by adding the following code in `/__mocks__/@react-force/models.ts`:

```
//  /__mocks__/@react-force/models.ts
export const WindowEnv = jest.fn(() => {
    return {
        get: (varName: string): string => {
            switch (varName) {
                case 'API_URL': {
                    return 'http://localhost:8080';
                }
                default: {
                    return '';
                }
            }
        },
    };
});
```

Unfortunately this is making no difference. The test is not able to see the mock and throwing an error. What am I doing wrong?

The mocked class is available [here](https://github.com/nareshbhatia/trade-force/blob/master/trade-force-client/__mocks__/%40react-force/models.ts) along with the entire project.

Comment: The question doesn't mention where `__mocks__` is located but it appears that it's in project root, and the project is CRA. It should be in src, see https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7539

Comment: You hit it in the head, Estus. As soon as I moved the __mocks__ folder under /src, everything started working! Please add your comment as an answer and I will mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jest documentation states:

> If the module you are mocking is a Node module (e.g.: lodash), the mock should be placed in the `__mocks__` directory adjacent to node_modules (unless you configured roots to point to a folder other than the project root) and will be automatically mocked.

This way global module mocks don't interfere with local ones that reside in `src`.

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7539) for `node_modules` mocks in Create React App projects. `__mocks__` needs to be moved inside `src`.

Comment: I spent way too much time on trying to find and fix the issue to this. You're a life saver thank you